# Regex Arabic letters with or without special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following regex to match Arabic letters. I would like to accept also the following, characters `,.()-` and space character, however right now its using the boolean or between groups, the arabic letter should be mandator, so it won't accept for example only space or any of characters listed above.

Shouldn't match characters without Arabic letters

- 
- `,()-`

Should match

- `.()-,سشييتنسشاي`
- `سشييتنسشاي.(ي)-,`

```js
^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd])*$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, the rules are:

1. Must have at least one character in Arabic script
2. Must consist only of Arabic script, spaces, and `,.()-`

If so, you want:

- A positive lookahead for an Arabic character somewhere in the string, combined with
- `^` and `$` anchors requiring that everything between them be Arabic or `.,()-` or a space

If so, you can do that with Unicode property escapes (ES2018+, supported in up-to-date Firefox, Chrome/Chromium, Safari, Brave, and Edge [v79+]; or you can use libs like http://xregexp.com/):

```
const rex = /^(?=.*?\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic})[- ().,\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}]+$/u;
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /^(?=.*?\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic})[- ().,\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}]+$/u;

const shouldNotMatch = [" ", ",()-"];

const shouldMatch = ["سشييتنسشاي", ".()-,سشييتنسشاي", "سشييتنسشاي.(ي)-,"];

for (const str of shouldNotMatch) {
    const result = rex.test(str);
    console.log(str, result, result ? "ERROR" : "Good");
}

for (const str of shouldMatch) {
    const result = rex.test(str);
    console.log(str, result, result ? "Good" : "ERROR");
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into the various Unicode improvements in JavaScript over the last few years in Chapters 10 and 15 of my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.